# Speed up asp.net initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-6

Asp.net application takes an eternity to start as it tries to copy compiled binaries to:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

As I visit additional pages, IIS caches additional dlls.

How can I get IIS to cache all dlls, for all pages immediately on the first hit to the initial page?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add warmup calls into each module used in each DLL into your `Global.Application_Start`.  .NET 4.x has lazy initialization (to reduce initialization time by not initializing anything that you don't explicitly use.  If you use everything up front, the initialization will be done at that time.  You will need to ensure that every static member that is used gets used during the initialization.  That will require a careful examination of the decompiled code for the DLLs you are using, or actually making calls to the any functions you want to prewarm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for application warmup
Some options to improve website performance comes with IIS server modules

You can have a look at **Application Initialization Module for IIS 7.5**

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization

for IIS 6.0
[IIS: web applications warmup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063461/iis-web-applications-warmup)